# How to get back to "enter SIM pin" screen?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-550, pin

When I start up my phone I can get past the screen where I am to enter the SIM pin by pressing the Windows button.

But how do I get back to this screen now that I would like to enter the pin code to unlock the SIM card? (I could just reboot the phone again but that cannot possibly be the only way?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call any number, the screen will popup..